# Confusion related to torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

This is a passage from my physics textbook explaining the basics of torque.

[image]

Over here, AB is perpendicular to the plane right? r×F is also perpendicular to the plane. So why do we need to multiply|r×F| with cos theta to get the component of it along OA or AB? Shouldn't it be |r×F| since both the vectors are parallel?

Comment: The book says the force may not be on the plane, but that does not mean it is perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

$ \vec {OP} $ is not perpendicular to the axis AB. The axis is arbitrary, the force is arbitrary, and the $ \vec r $ is also arbitrary. In that case, the torque is $ \vec T = \vec R \times \vec F$ and you'll see that this torque is only perpendicular to the radial vector, and force vector, but has an angle $ \theta $ with the AB axis. This means this torque has 2 components, one along AB, and another along an axis perpendicular to AB. We don't worry about the torque perpendicular to AB, as it doesn't cause any rotational effects (it is a fixed axis rotation). In order to add torques in a meaningful way, we take the component along the rotating axis and do calculations. Another way to write this is: $$\vec T_{AB} =((\vec r \times \vec F)\cdot \hat{n})\hat{n} $$ where $ \hat{n} $ is the direction unit vector of the axis AB and $\vec T_{AB}$ is the torque along axis AB. The only condition here is that the axis doesn't rotate, and remains fixed.

Comment: So AB is not  perpendicular to the plane or OP does not lie on the plane?

Comment: You should understand there is no plane, the body is a 3 dimensional, rigid body with an arbitrary axis. The position of each particle is determined by the choice of origin, but the torque about the fixed axis is determined only based on the perpendicular distance of each particle from the axis AB. I don't know why you are talking about planes, there is no plane

Comment: Thank you so much, I was assuming the axis to be perpendicular to the plane. I did not know it was arbitrary. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In most cases, it is illustrated to be perpendicular to some plane (the plane of the paper or the screen you're viewing, for example) but this is just for convenience, and simplification.